# git report files changed on which I did not work

Tags: git

`git status` reports a large set of file to be “new”, “modified” and “deleted” in a directory tree I never worked in. In Subversion  I would do a `svn revert --recursive iPhone` (I don't work on the iPhone version of the App) and be done with. But with Git things are not easy. With Git everything it is always complicated.

So I am in bit of a panic because the iPhone team would tear me apart if I mess up there code. And it would be a mayor mess as more then 50 files are reported changed.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you do a `git add .` when you didn't mean to? That could've added everything in the directory that was not explicitly ignored by `.gitignore`

Comment: At what point did the files become "new", "modified", and "deleted"? Did you switch branches? Modify that code in your working copy? Pull changes?

Comment: What does `git diff` display? You could have changes to the file mode. If need be, you can always revert everything with `git reset HEAD --hard` (be careful with this)

Comment: @yoda: I do `git add .` in my own directory (which would be Android). I don't do it the iPhone directory. I don't do it on the root directory. I checked the terminal history — it did not happen accidental as well. So **NO**.

Comment: @Chris: After a `git pull` things went wrong.

Comment: @Chris Rasys: `git diff` reports nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent Git command is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Be aware that this will **throw away** any local changes you have made in the whole tree (since the last commit). Be careful with this, it's a good idea to take a backup of your entire repository until you check that this really does what you want.

Comment: that give me a «fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.»

Comment: Why backup the entire repository? That seems a little silly considering the nature of git.

Comment: Looks ok again: `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: I am i a loop now. After the reset I can push any more: *error: failed to push some refs to … Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.* — If i do the pull as suggested the I am back a square one.

Comment: @Martin: Stupid question, do you know how to resolve a merge conflict in Git? It sounds like you get a conflict when you pull but haven't resolved it yet.

Comment: @Chris Rasys: If there is uncommitted work in some other part of the tree, then `git reset --hard` will throw it away. I think that caught me once when I was learning Git.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Merge conflict in a directory tree where I have not change a single file?. Which is strictly read only for me? But then, Subversion can create conflicts where there aren't any. I guess move the work copy away and get a new one.

Comment: @Martin: There's probably nothing wrong with your repository (Git is more robust than Subversion in that regard). Retrying with another copy will probably do exactly the same thing. Unfortunately, we don't have enough information to tell you what's going on, so you may be best off consulting a local Git expert.

Answer (score 2):

If you're afraid of losing work, you *should* be able to use [`git stash`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) to squirrel away your local changes in case you need them later. This will give you a clean working directory and still allow you to access your uncommitted changes if you need them later. From the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html):

> Use git stash when you want to record
>   the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to
>   go back to a clean working directory.
>   The command saves your local
>   modifications away and reverts the
>   working directory to match the HEAD
>   commit.
>
> The modifications stashed away by this
>   command can be listed with git stash
>   list, inspected with git stash show,
>   and restored (potentially on top of a
>   different commit) with git stash
>   apply. Calling git stash without any
>   arguments is equivalent to git stash
>   save. A stash is by default listed as
>   "WIP on branchname …", but you can
>   give a more descriptive message on the
>   command line when you create one.
>
> The latest stash you created is stored
>   in refs/stash; older stashes are found
>   in the reflog of this reference and
>   can be named using the usual reflog
>   syntax (e.g. stash@{0} is the most
>   recently created stash, stash@{1} is
>   the one before it, stash@{2.hours.ago}
>   is also possible).